# Where to spend Fleet Commendations?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

I have amassed quite a few of these, as I rather enjoy the space battles. Although I've not found anywhere to trade them in yet. I've had a brief look around the Republic Fleet both Carrik station and the other ships, but didn't find anything.

Does anyone know if you can spend them, or if this is to be added later when they update the space part of the game?

Comment: **Spoiler Alert** Once found, buy the Power Converter with your first 30 commendations. lvl 25 required, though.

Comment: Cannot recommend the above comment enough. It won't save your life, it will ensure your life won't *need* saving because everything will start exploding when you look at it funny.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The commendation vendor can be found in the same room as the Starship Upgrades vendor on Carrick Station (NE quadrant, if I recall correctly). He's just not standing behind the counter, but by the racks just next to the counter.

**Edit**: Confirmed. It's a protocol droid named S-40.

Comment: For the empire: the trade quadrant (SW). Droid is called S-1A0.

Answer (score 4):

There should be a vendor who sells ship gear, along with some vanity items. At the Imperial Fleet, he's in the 'Market' quadrant, downstairs from the GTN.

Comment: Yeah, I've spent a while on Carrik Station (Republic fleet station) looking around, using the map magnifier without luck. I will look again, but I was hoping someone would know :)